# Magento I enabled the ssl options from admin and the store showing 404 error

Tags: php, magento

I just enabled the ssl options from the admin and when i checked it by refreshing the page my front end and admin pages showing the 404 error. what's the issue? can any body help?
 i am not even able to change the setting from admin.

Thanks...

Comment: Where did  u make chages for ssl

Comment: admin/configuration->web->unsecure and secure ai just added the https for secure url and said yes use secure url in front end pages and admin pages

Comment: it helped me but css has gone. how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are u getting 404 error, i can simply help you getting the previous settings back. so that you can have access to your admin panel. you can open mysql and look for a table core_config and check out the what you changed there, replace that with the previous and refresh your web page. I hope this will help ...

Comment: it helped me but css is not applied at all. how to solve the css problem?

Comment: Go to Magento Configuration Settings and select a default theme for design